# How to check if object in list in Django Views

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to check whether an id matches an element in a list inside a Django view. I have looped through a filtered model and have appended the item.id to a list called items , I can see in my terminal that the list is being printed, but my "if" condition is not working :

if product_obj in items:
print('will be removed')
added = False

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong ? any ideas?

views.py

```
def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')

    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("Show message to user, product is gone?")
            return redirect("cart:home")
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(items_cart_id=cart_obj)
        items = [] 
        for item in cart_items:
            items.append(item.item.id)
        print(items)
        if product_obj in items:
            print('will be removed')
            added = False
        else:
            newitem = CartItem(item=product_obj, items_cart=cart_obj, quantity=1)
            newitem.save()
            added = True
        request.session['cart_items'] = cart_items.count()
        # return redirect(product_obj.get_absolute_url())
        if request.is_ajax(): # Asynchronous JavaScript And XML / JSON
            print("Ajax request")
            json_data = {
                "added": added,
                "removed": not added,
                "cartItemCount": cart_items.count()
            }
            return JsonResponse(json_data, status=200) # HttpResponse
            # return JsonResponse({"message": "Error 400"}, status=400) # Django Rest Framework
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

Comment: `items` is a list containing _ids_ while `product_obj` is an instance of `Product` perhaps you want to be writing  `if product_obj.id in items:` or `if product_obj.pk in items:`

Comment: if you want to search for product_obj id in the list then use `if product_obj.id in items`

Comment: ok it's product_obj.id